# Merge two DF with a columns are partially similar

Tags: python, pandas

I have two separate files, one from our service providers and the other is internal (HR).

The service providers write the names of our employer in different ways, there are those who write it in firstname lastname format, or first letter of the firstname and the last name or lastname firstname...while the HR file includes separately the first and last name.

My idea is to sort of comparing the two files in the column first name and last name and retrieve the best match.
I'm using Python in my data cleaning.

Comment: Please provide an example of what the data looks like (use fake names). This would help us a lot.

Comment: This is a non-trivial issue, and can range widely in the required complexity. Please add a few specific examples of rows that SHOULD link, and some that should NOT.